# Google Sheets - How to format numerical contents of data validation list?

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I'm using Data Validation to give the user a list of valid prices they can select from.  These are on their sheet in "financial" format such as

```
2.00
2.50
3.00
```

etc.  But in the actual dropdown menu, they appear unformatted, like

```
  2
2.5
  3
```

etc.  Once selected however, they do get formatted as financial data because I've formatted that column appropriately.

How can I get the actual dropdown list presented by Data Validation, to be correctly formatted as desired?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, at this time it's not possible to apply the desired format (0.00), but other formats like date, percentage works fine. Currency also doesn't work.

Comment: Wow that's highly unfortunate. By chance do you have any link or citation for that information?

Comment: I don't have any link or citation, that is why I started my answer with AFAIK   .